# How to hibernate in a full-encrypted disk using LVM?

Tags: encryption, hibernate, lvm

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and set up my system using LVM with full disk encryption. Then I installed uswsusp and the loading failed. I searched the web and found that this is because my swap partition is encrypted. But all solutions I found on the web deal with the case where only the swap partition is encrypted (not using LVM to encrypt the whole disk). Is there any way to enable hibernate on a fully-encrypted disk?

Comment: What have you tried?